# Manipulating data after styling

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I am totally new to python/pandas and trying to do a simple task of splitting a text field (delimited by commas) in a dataframe into multiple columns where the comma is the delimiter.  The file is originally in Excel.  The field is not left justified, so I left justify it using the following command:

```py
df=df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
```

This command does left justify the column, but it also transforms the dataframe into a Styler object, which then doesn't allow me to execute commands that I normally would on a dataframe.  I did use the df=df.data command after the transformation, and that does seem to change it back to a dataframe, but the field reverts back to a right justified column.  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Import your DF from Excel, do your business and then only at the end apply a .style.

Comment: Hello, can you share some examples. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
In excel, numbers are right justified, while text is left by default and it can be modified. What is your use case for a need to change the alignment while processing in pandas DF?

Comment: Hi, the data is imported from Excl into a df, and is then loaded into a SQL srver tbl. The script is currently written to load the data and works fine.  One of the colums is a comma delimit text field which can be up to 24 values.  In Excel, it is right justified.  We want to do the left justif in Pandas/Python rather than Excel.  And once it's left justif, I can parse out the field into 24 separate cols.  I use the command I mentioned before and it does the justify but the field but it is no longer a df; it becomes a Styler object, and you can't do normal commands on a Styler object.  Thanks!

Comment: @user19210181 Show the code how you split data. It's not obvious right now why you need left-alignment.

Comment: Hi. If the field was left justif in Excel, my Pandas code to split it into 24 separate columns would be something like df['Col1']=df.str.split(',',expand=True)[0]. Then df['Col2']=df.str.split(',',expand=True)[1].  etc...all the way to 24. But since the field is right justified, the command doesn't work correctly.  In most cases, this field is null, so all 24 fields will be null, and sometimes it will only have a few values like '1, 10, 20'.  This means I want Col1 to be 1, Col10 to be 10, Col20 to be 20, and all the rest of the Col values to be null.

Comment: Perhaps I don't need to do any left justification.  I just need to create 24 columns, i.e, COL1, COL 2...COL24.  Each column will be either null or 1 depending on the string value.  If the string value contains a '1', then COL1 will be set to 1, if the string value doesn't contain a 1, then COL1 will be null.  If the string value contains a '2', then COL2 will be set to 1, if the string value doesn't contain a 2, then COL2 will be null, etc...if the string value has a '10', then COL10 will be 1.  If there is no '10', COL10 will be null.  Hope this helps...thanks!